# Reinforced.Typings cannot handle attributes on properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reinforced-typings

I have an ASP.NET Core project using ASP.NET Identity. Some classes cannot be exported since their properties contain attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`. If I ignore such properties, everything works fine.

Example class:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Since I don't want to strip out these attributes, what is the recommended course of action?

```
[assembly: TsGlobal(
    CamelCaseForMethods = true,
    CamelCaseForProperties = true,
    GenerateDocumentation = true,
    UseModules = true,
    DiscardNamespacesWhenUsingModules = true)]

namespace X
{
    public static class ReinforcedTypingsConfiguration
    {
        public static void Configure(ConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder
                .ExportAsInterface<LoginViewModel>()
                .AutoI(false)
                .WithProperty(x => x.RememberMe)
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

Other than that, it seems that `UseModules` does the opposite of what I want it to do. When set to `true`, the generated ts file doesn't contain any modules. When set to `false`, I get `module` in my ts files.

Also, when dividing types among files, I get strange folder names on mac that contain `\` for every `.` in my namespace. Can I just flatten out the structure? And completely ignore backend namespaces?

In the above configuration (and I use file splitting) I get the annoying error message `error MSB3552: Resource file "**/*.resx" cannot be found.`.

Comment: cannot be exported?, you mean can not be serialized?.. System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations attributes are used for model validation, they should not cause any problem in serialization. Can you post the error you are getting.

Comment: You have provided too few details, but from current code I can see that you might be missing ```[TsInterface]```/```[TsClass]``` attribute on your model or fluent call ```.ExprotAsInterface```/```.ExportAsClass```.
Please provide your exporting configuration - then I can answer. Currently I have created test .NET Core project on my machine and successfully exported your model simply by adding ```[TsInterface]``` above it. [Reinforced.Typings](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings) does not interfer with ```System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations``` attributes somehow.

Comment: As soon as I fix the issue `error MSB3552: Resource file"**/*.resx" cannot be found.` I will write additional details...

Comment: According to your code, RT expectedly exports only one field - ```RememberMe```.
Try to use ```.WithPublicProperties()```

About modules: according to [documentation](https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Configuration-attributes#TsGlobal) ```UseModules``` option enables generation of TS modules system-compatible code. It does not mean that you will get ```module``` keyword within your code.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: When I add `WithPublicProperties`, I get the error I mentioned in the post itself. Regardless of that, the above configuration will produce the resx error. So, two errors in one. And the problem with the file names as well.

Comment: Okay, got it. Try to update to version 1.4.2 - there it should be fixed.
```\``` in file names is actually automatical files division. On Windows RT is creating directory structure like ```My.Name.Space.Type``` revealed to ```My/Name/Space/Type.ts```. 
Use ```.ExportTo``` to specify exact file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 1.4.2 to fix this issue.